# Marvel Api - JavaScript: How to display Comic info in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, api

I'm using the Marvel API and I would like to display comic information in a modal after clicking on a comic card but the problem is that:

-the modal displays all the 20 comics description instead of one.

-or modal showed the same description for all 20 comics when clicked on a card.

I guess it has something to do with the *comic ID* but I don't know how to get the ID nor how to connect it with the modal.  When I try to get it, either I get all Id's or only the first comic's id.

The result of the request looks like this and I don't know how could I connect a card to it's related Id:

```js
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 90122, digitalId: 0, title: "Symbiote Spider-Man: King in Black (2020) #5", issueNumber: 5, variantDescription: "", …}
1: {id: 80471, digitalId: 54905, title: "Marvel (2020) #3", issueNumber: 3, variantDescription: "", …}
2: {id: 65123, digitalId: 0, title: "Edge Of Venomverse (Trade Paperback)", issueNumber: 0, variantDescription: "", …}
3: {id: 78327, digitalId: 0, title: "Rocket Raccoon and Groot: Tall Tails (Trade Paperback)"..}
```

The html and javascript on codepen (in the JS I marked the area where I'm stuck):
https://codepen.io/lillae/pen/poRGLvg?editors=1010

In that code I use the forEach() method but with that it displays all the comics information in 1 modal and I don't know how to make it recognize the comic that it's clicked on.

I would be very happy for some help as I'm stuck for a while on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All , You are getting all the ids because of this code.

```
    const marvel = data2.data.results; //20 array of 20 comics
    let output = '';
    marvel.forEach((comic) => {
      output += `
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="modalPic">
      <img ${comic.thumbnail.path}/portrait_incredible.jpg" alt=""
        class="modal-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8" id="infoModal">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">${comic.title}         </h5>
      <p>${comic.description}</p>
    </div>
    `;
    });

    modalInfo.innerHTML = output;
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`${err.message}`);
    renderError(`${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

To show a particular Id detail in modal , you should get only one id first.
Build a `button` on which when user select from the list of comic you get the id of that particular comic. SO that you can search it from the response from the api. After getting the id example`22331`, use in built array method in javascript `.find()`.

Use like this :-

```
res // response from api (must be array of object)

res.find(comic => {
     return comic.id === userSelected.id;
})
```

This code block will return an array consisting only that comic which has same id as that of the user selected .

Then `.map()` the array to your modal.